# Trying to compile a script from github but getting errors

Tags: bash, makefile

I'm trying to install https://github.com/xxorde/librekinect

but I'm running into the following issue:

```
$ make
make pc
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/pi/librekinect-master'
make -C /lib/modules/3.18.5+/build M= modules
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/pi/librekinect-master'
make[2]: *** /lib/modules/3.18.5+/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/librekinect-master'
Makefile:31: recipe for target 'pc' failed
make[1]: *** [pc] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/librekinect-master'
Makefile:24: recipe for target 'default' failed
make: *** [default] Error 2
```

I tried searching for `*** /lib/modules/3.18.5+/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.` on google but that produced nothing helpful.

What am I missing?

Comment: what are you compiling on? are you sure all the dependencies are ok ?

Comment: probably missing some header files for your kernel, try to install the development package like `linux-headers-$(uname -r)`

Comment: I'm compiling on a raspberry pi (raspbian) and I don't even know what the dependencies are or how to find that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are working on raspberry pi, you should follow [the recipe here](https://github.com/xxorde/librekinect#example-for-the-raspberry-pi).  Mostly, I think you miss parts of the toolchain (at least build-essentials and likely the headers).  I would follow that example step by step.